# How to avoid auto rounding for double in java

Tags: java

1. How to remove auto rounding for double. Below is my code

   double balance = 19153570.76;
2. While generating i am getting the output as 19153571 instead of 19153570.76 
   so how to avoid the auto rounding to getting the real balance

Comment: show your code please

Comment: There's no auto rouning. Most probably you have a problem with your output code. Which you don't show.

Answer (score 0):

there is no auto rounding in Java, anyways I think the problem you got is that you are printing an Integer instead of double, if you put here your code it would make more sence